# zf2 route to bookmark

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, bookmarks

In zf2, how do we write the routing to point to a bookmark in a page?  For example, if a target page had this:

```
<h2 id="tips">Useful Tips Section</h2>
```

and we want the router to generate this:

```
<a href="target_page#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

what route types should be used and what's the syntax?

Comment: You can use the `fragment` option of the URL view helper, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154357/zf2-url-helper-customization-to-add-achnor-for-angularjs-router#22162928).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?= $this->url('your_route', [], ['fragment' => 'tips']) ?>">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [fragments](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html#fragments) option of the URL View Helper can be used for this purpose.  Fragments can also be used in Controller Plugins like the [Redirect Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#redirect-plugin).